# Android email validation for english and arabic characters

Tags: android, regex, email-validation

I am currently using this regular expression pattern to validate email addresses:

```
android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailAddress).matches();
```

It doesn't work with Arabic characters. I need it to work with both English and Arabic characters.

This is the regex pattern I have incorporate for android (OS) in my project:

```
    public static final Pattern EMAIL_ADDRESS
    = Pattern.compile(
        "[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}" +
        "\\@" +
        "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}" +
        "(" +
            "\\." +
            "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" +
        ")+"
    );
```

I am not regex expert. I could use some help figuring out how to support both.

Comment: Try replacing all `a-zA-Z` with `\\p{L}`. Or even `\\p{L}\\p{M}` to account for diacritics.

Comment: Any feedback?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the best answer, but I was able to get it to work by adding the aribic characters:

```
[\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669a-zA-Z0-9\+\.\_\%\-\+]{1,256}\@[\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669a-zA-Z0-9][\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,64}(\.[\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669a-zA-Z0-9][\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,25})+
```

[Here's an example on regexr! (it doesn't display Arabic selection properly, but it is selected)](http://regexr.com/3flhq)