# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid topic name: الصحة_التغذية does not match the allowed format [a-zA-Z0-9-_.~%]{1,900}

Tags: android, firebase

Firebase Topic Subscription give error when i use topic name other than English

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("الصحة_التغذية")
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this,new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            String msg = "Success";
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                msg = "Failed";
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
        }
```

Comment: please check this link. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150333/android-email-validation-for-english-and-arabic-characters)

Comment: as the error suggests, non english characters are not allowed for topic names

Comment: The error message is telling you which characters are legal.  Lowercase and uppercase English letters, numbers, hyphen, underscore, period, tilde, and percent.  Glyphs from other languages are outside what is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

The Solution is : You must have to use English for topic name.

You can do it as below :

```
if(strTopic.equals("الصحة_التغذية")){
    strTopic="YourEnglishTopicName";
}

FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(strTopic)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this,new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            String msg = "Success";
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                msg = "Failed";
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
        }
```

Where, `strTopic` might be any dynamic value for your topic or may be predefined value according to your need.

Comment: No, Topic name must be in arabic. I can't convert it to english.

Comment: Then check here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150333/android-email-validation-for-english-and-arabic-characters

Comment: this link is not helpful related to this question.

Comment: @NaumanAfsar You don't have a choice.  Firebase requires the topic to be in english.  It will not accept any other characters except english letters, numbers, and a few symbols like '-'

Comment: But it happened in ios.

Comment: just for english not for other languages